# Cannot upload images to S3 from Django backend and Nextjs frontend vercel

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, next.js

I have an e-commerce site built with Django and nextjs. Previously it was hosted on hostinger but recently I moved the API backend to AWS Lambda and the frontend to vercel. I'm storing the product images in S3. The problem I;m facing is after the migration, I'm not able to upload the images from my nextjs frontend. I have tried uploading the images from postman and Django admin panel and it worked. It just not works from the nextjs frontend.

Here is the error:

`An error occurred (400) when calling the HeadObject operation: Bad Request`

I'm using `django-storages` to upload my images to S3.

I'm using FormData to send images from frontend to backend.

frontend submit function:

```
function submit() {
    setIsLoading(true);
    var myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append("Authorization", `Bearer ${session?.token?.access}`);
    myHeaders.append("Cookie", "django_language=en");

    var formdata = new FormData();
    formdata.append("name", name);
    formdata.append("desc", desc);
    formdata.append("length", length);
    formdata.append("height", height);
    formdata.append("width", width);
    formdata.append("measure", measurements);
    formdata.append("origin", origin);
    formdata.append("signed", signed);
    formdata.append("reproduce", reproduce);
    formdata.append("reproduce_days", reproduce_days);
    formdata.append("image", img);
    formdata.append("reg_price", price);
    formdata.append("cat", category);
    formdata.append("year", year);
    formdata.append("newcat", otherCategory);
    formdata.append("newsubcat", otherSubCategory);
    formdata.append("newmedium", otherMedium);
    formdata.append("subcat", subCategory);
    formdata.append("medium", medium);
    formdata.append("orientation", orientation);
    formdata.append("stock_quantity", quantity);

    var requestOptions = {
      method: "POST",
      headers: myHeaders,
      body: formdata,
      redirect: "follow",
    };

    fetch(
      `${API_URL}/profile/vendor/${session?.token?.user?.id}/add-product/?curr=INR`,
      requestOptions
    )
      .then((response) => response.text())
      .then((result) => console.log(result))
      .catch((error) => console.log("error", error));
  }
```

Note: My Lambda function and S3 bucket are not in the same region.

Comment: Have you modified your CORS list in django?

Comment: Yes the domain is already listed in the CORS list

Comment: Can you check the network calls in web insepctor? Do you see there more details about the request?